# Discrete Math: Given a set of integers, permute, calculate expected number of integers that remain same position

Tags: math, statistics, probability, discrete-mathematics

So we are given a set of integers from 0 to n. This is then randomized. The goal is to calculate the number of expected integers which remain in the same position in both lists. I have tried to set up two indicator variables for each integer and then mapping it to the two different sets, but I don't really know how to go from there.

Comment: As a question of probability this is off-topic.  If it's a question of programming, show us your code.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are trying to calculate the number `X` of integers that remain in the same position for any given particular case (sample), or the expected value `E(X)` of the random variable `X`.

Answer (score 0):

The random variable `X`, representing the number of your integers which remain in the same position after randomisation, follows the binomial distribution with `n+1` trials and a probability of `1/(n+1)`, therefore the expected number of integers remaining in place is 1.

My reasoning is:

- Each integer can move to any other position in the list after randomisation, with equal probability. So whether an integer remains in place can be considered a Bernoulli distribution, with probability `1/(n+1)`, since there are `n+1` possible position it could move to, and only 1 position for it to have remained in place.
- There are therefore `n+1` Bernoulli distributions, all with the same probability, and all independent of each other. (A Bernoulli distribution represents a yes / no outcome where the yes has a given probability.)
- The binomial distribution is defined as the number of successes in a given number of identical independent trials, or (equivalently) the number of "yes" outcomes in a given number of independent Bernoulli distributions with the same probability.
- The number of your integers which remain in place after randomisation is therefore a bimonial distribution, probability `1/(n+1)` and with `n+1` trials.
- The mean of a binomial distribution with `n` trials with probability `p` is `np`, therefore in your case the expected number of integers remaining in place is `(n+1) . (1/(n+1))` which is 1.

For more info on the binomial distribution, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).